# Display information of a Google Doc as the HTML of a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I want to create a Chrome extension that display the content of a Google Doc (a doc or spreadsheet)  on the HTML "popup.html". when clicked on the extension in the bar.

Is there any tutorial, reference or alternative that I have to do that quickly and clean?

Comment: Who owns the Google Document? Is it public?

Comment: Is not public, that is the reason why I need to create the extension in first place.